# Copy specific rows into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy specific rows from Sheet A into a specific row-position in Sheet B with variables.

**What it should do:**
Starting in Sheet B:
I am looking in "Sheet B" for values > 0 through a specific column (e.g. "V") , top down.
If there is a value > 0 (e.g. = 4), take this value and copy all rows out of "Sheet A" with this value in column A under the position where the value = 4 was found in "Sheet B".
Repeat this beginning this time from the first new pasted row in "Sheet B" until every row in Sheet B is being checked.
The copied row can contain again values > 0 in "V" and that's why I want to start checking one line under.

What I tried:

**1. Copy range from "Sheet 1" based on given input value from cell:**

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
j = 5
For i = 1 To 10232
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value = InputCell Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1)
    j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, post what you have tried, show some minimun effort. Also, this question has been asked like 10000000 times, so if you search for copying rows you will see millions of examples that you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you :) You are right, I edited my post!

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

In *Sheet1*, running this:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To 21
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "V").Value > 0 Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce this in *Sheet2*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The copy process works perfect :)

using: If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value = InputCell Then ...

But the main problem now is to go through the Sheet2. I will post below my idea